# Why can I not std::partition this std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

This doesn't build and I don't understand the compilation error.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, size_t> occurences = { { 10, 2 }, { 20, 5 }, { 30, 0 }, { 40, 5 }, { 50, 0 }, { 100, 9 } };

    auto newEnd = std::partition(occurences.begin(), occurences.end(), [](const std::pair<int, size_t> &p)
        {
        return p.second == 0;
        });

    return 0;
}
```

g++ complains as follows. VS2013 is even more cryptic.

> /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of
>   'void std::pair<_T1, _T2>::swap(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 =
>   const int; _T2 = long unsigned int]':
>   /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:473:7:   required from
>   'void std::swap(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1
>   = const int; _T2 = long unsigned int]' /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:148:11:   required
>   from 'void std::iter_swap(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2) [with
>   _ForwardIterator1 = std::__detail::_Node_iterator, false, false>; _ForwardIterator2 =
>   std::__detail::_Node_iterator,
>   false, false>]' /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1500:20: 
>   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__partition(_ForwardIterator,
>   _ForwardIterator, _Predicate, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _ForwardIterator = std::__detail::_Node_iterator, false, false>; _Predicate = main()::&)>]'
>   /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4524:30:   required from
>   '_BIter std::partition(_BIter, _BIter, _Predicate) [with _BIter =
>   std::__detail::_Node_iterator,
>   false, false>; _Predicate = main()::&)>]' main.cpp:12:4:   required from here
>   /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:416:6: error: no matching
>   function for call to 'swap(const int&, const int&)'   swap(first,
>   __p.first);

[See it live on Coliru here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb482f8d0d4f7810)

As far as I can tell this map meets the std::partition type requirements listed on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) so I'm stumped. My question is why doesn't it build?

Comment: What do you want this to do? A `std::map` is always sorted. A `std::unordered_map` has no fixed notion of order. In either case, partitioning doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jtbandes The reason I want to do this, is that this is a minimal example where the actual code has a map as the appropriate container for other reasons. My usage here is one small part where I want the ints (indexes) that have zero occurrences. I can workaround by std::copy the contents into a vector.

Comment: You missed the [ValueSwappable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ValueSwappable) requirement on the iterators.

Comment: @molbdnilo No, what I missed is what Jonathon Wakely has answered below about the actul element type. `std::pair<int, size_t>` is value swappable but not `std::pair<const int, size_t>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is because the elements of a `map` and `unordered_map` are `std::pair<const Key, value>` *not* `std::pair<Key, Value>`, so you can't re-order them using an algorithm like `std::partition` because the `const Key` can't be modified:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'swap(const int&, const int&)'
```

Only the map itself can re-order the elements, and it keeps them in whatever order it needs to in order to maintain its invariants. If you re-order them you will corrupt the map's internal data structures.

Comment: Thank you for the edit to the question, it was a typo.

Answer (score 5):

`std::partition` reorders the elements in the provided container, however you can not reorder the elements of a `std::map` - it has a predefined **fixed** order of its elements. The standard guarantees that when iterating over the elements of a map, you will always iterate them in increasing order.

As you mention `unordered_map` in the title I will also mention that unlike `map` it does not give guarantees about the order of its elements but reordering its elements is also not possible. After all `unordered_map` is **unordered** so it will never give any guarantee about the order in which you iterate over its elements.

Answer (score 1):

All other answers are correct. `unordered_map` doesn't let you rearrange its elements in the same way that `map` doesn't and that's it. However there is a deeper conceptual problem.

When you created the `unordered_map` you decided that the order (any order) wouldn't matter, and suddenly you want the order to matter (partition operation). 
If you want a range, this requires your elements in a different container for sure, one in which *the* partition order matters.

You can always convert the partition into a comparison criterion, in which case you can use a `multiset` to store a new version of your collection.

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<set>

using std::cout; using std::cerr;

int main(){

    std::unordered_map<int, size_t> occurences = { { 10, 2 }, { 20, 5 }, { 30, 0 }, { 40, 5 }, { 50, 0 }, { 100, 9 } };

    auto null_second_pred = [](auto& e){return e.second == 0;};
    auto null_second_comp = [&](auto& a, auto& b){return null_second_pred(a) and (not null_second_pred(b));};
    std::multiset<std::pair<int, size_t>, decltype(null_second_comp)> 
        occurences2(occurences.begin(), occurences.end(), null_second_comp);

    assert( std::is_partitioned(occurences2.begin(), occurences2.end(), null_second_pred) );

}
```

(More conceptually you can move the elements into the new container but it won't make a difference in this case. 
Also you can't use `multimap` because you would loose information and the ordering criterion can't be on the second part of the pair.)